# Question "Martin Luther and the Bible" should not have been closed

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

@YOONJI's question [Martin Luther and the Bible](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/50732/martin-luther-and-the-bible) was marked my community vote as a duplicate of [Why was Martin Luther attempting to change the canon](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4474/why-was-martin-luther-attempting-to-change-the-canon). I don't believe this should be the case.

Richard's 2011 question was threefold:

1. What was Martin Luther's purpose in removing Hebrews, James, Jude, and Revelation from the Bible?
2. Was Martin Luther's removing these books a doctrinal stance against these four books?
3. Do these four books contain doctrine that we should, per Martin Luther, not believe?

On the other hand, YOONJ's question was whether "any of the changes implemented by Martin Luther affects [sic] our current modern Bibles in any way".

This is a completely different question and is broader than what was asked by @Richard and has a different answer.  Luther, for example, eliminated all of the Deuterocanonical books from the Bible that was recognized by the Roman Catholic Church whence Luther came, and were included in the Old Testament canon by multiple first-millennial Church councils. Neither of the [existing](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/45620/30) [answers](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/4476/30) address this.  The answer to YOONJ's question is almost certainly yes, Luther's changes did affect our current modern Bibles, since most Protestant Bibles exclude the Deuterocanonical books, whereas Catholic and Orthodox Christian Bibles included them before Luther and continue to do so.

I suggest unmarking YOONJ's question as a duplicate.  It is not a duplicate and it is not answered by the answers to the other question.

Comment: The question has been edited to clarify. Unfortunately, it now includes questions that are primarily opinion based and truth questions about why Luther did it and whether he was right to do so. That's why I voted not to reopen it.

Comment: @LeeWoofenden I've further edited it to more clearly distinguish it from the other question (particularly the title) and remove the opinion-based part.

Comment: YOONJ's original question was so unspecific it could've been closed for being unclear. It's now clearer, but it also has no references and is factually wrong. So sure, let's reopen it, but I hope to see lots of downvotes on it too.

Comment: + [status-completed]